# How do I hit internal API with Authentication in Blazor Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a API endpoint in my controller:

```
[HttpDelete("delete/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething(int id)
{
    var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
}
```

And I have a Blazor page where I want to invoke that:

```
private async Task MyAction()
{
    var result = await HttpClient.DeleteAsync($"/api/mycontroller/delete/{someId}");
}
```

I am logged in on my Blazor page and I want to pass along the identity/authentication to the api controller. In my case, the GetUserAsync on the controller side always returns null. I am using the default Identity.Application authentication sheme.

I tried modifying the request header with the data from the IHttpContextAccessor but I didn't get it to work and I don't think this is the way you are supposed to do this.

Comment: If you are using AppContext to get usermanager, it won’t work in blazor server app. Have you tried **AuthenticationStateProvider**, which can get the user. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#authenticationstateprovider-service

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by copying the auth cookie to the HttpClient.

```
var token = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Identity.Application"];
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", $".AspNetCore.Identity.Application={token}");
```

Comment: In Blazor Server you should not be using HttpContext, because of how SignalR works. Anything you get from HttpContext can be outdated and not true when using BlazorServer.